# Why am I getting a JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 24 path $.result?

Tags: string, gson

1.I have one JSON file:

(1).successful return json data:

```
{
    "code": 100,
    "result": {
        "pic": "http%3A%2F%2Fres1.adyun.com%2Fres1%2Fupload %2F40543%2Fidea_201609%2F14736434292154.jpg",
        "clickurl": "http%3A%2F%2Fs.adyun.com%2Fsdkclick%3Fa%3D3062120448_3895541760_4%26i %3D5575715%26c

%3D7DA0B90B6DF81BD015A97357FB7F%26d%3D924737536_557985792_4246247424_6040307314919997440%26e

%3Dd4ee13b64d2cd3f7_2%26g %3D0%26h%3D329d7b4280da7ffc%26s%3D29281%26k%3D2%26j%3D5%26l%3D0%26v%3D3%26r 

%3D687474703A2F2F7777772E786C7A73736A2E636F6D2F",
        "holycrap": "557985792_4246247424_6040307314919997440",
        "telno": ""
    }
}
```

(2)failure return json data:

```
{
    "code":-23, 

    "result":"no ad"
}
```

2.into a list of objects.

```
BaseRet baseRet = new Gson().fromJson(content, BaseRet.class);
```

3.Here's an object class I'm using.

BaseRet:

```
public class BaseRet {

    public int code;//": 100

    public AdData result;//<-
}
```

AdData:

```
public class AdData {
    public String pic;           
    public String clickurl;      
    public String clicknotifyurl;

    public String holycrap;      
    public String telno;         
    public String getClicknotifyurl() {
         return clicknotifyurl;
    }


    public void setClicknotifyurl(String clicknotifyurl) {
        this.clicknotifyurl = clicknotifyurl;
    }

    public String getClickurl() {
        return clickurl;
    }

    public void setClickurl(String clickurl) {
        this.clickurl = clickurl;
    }

    public String getHolycrap() {
        return holycrap;
    }

    public void setHolycrap(String holycrap) {
        this.holycrap = holycrap;
    }

    public String getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(String pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public String getTelno() {
        return telno;
    }

    public void setTelno(String telno) {
        this.telno = telno;
    }
}
```

4.But it throws me with

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 24 path $.result
```

5.Any ideas how should I fix it?

Comment: in the `BaseRet`, the class of `result` is `AdData`. but your second json data has `"result":"no ad"` which means `result` is string. gson is trying to deserialize string to `AdData` object and fails.

Comment: And the workaround is maybe defining `result` as `JsonElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key point is your failure response of result is a STRING, not JSONObject.
If you want to fix, pls do not use one key to represent different type.

e.g.

```html
class BaseRet<T>{
     int code;
     String msg;
     T result;
}
```

move failure result 'no ad' to param msg, let result to be null